# TemplateDoesNotExist at /poll/1/ -Django tutorial

Tags: python, django

I got an error, TemplateDoesNotExist at /polls/1/
I'm supposed to see the result of the vote after I vote.
Error is:

```
polls/details.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/1/
Django Version: 3.0.8
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
polls/details.html
Exception Location: C:\Users\JohnDoe\Documents\JaneDoe\Django\trydjango\tutorial\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py in get_template, line 19
Python Executable:  C:\Users\JohnDoe\Documents\JaneDoe\Django\trydjango\tutorial\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.8.4
```

detail.html

```
<h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>

{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}

<form action="{% url 'polls:vote' question.id %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}">
    <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label><br>
{% endfor %}
<input type="submit" value="Vote">
</form>
```

Templates are nested in a polls folder which is in a templates folder in the polls app.
I don't understand why I am getting an error in details.
How can I fix this?

Comment: Let's see your views.py. Think you pasted your models by mistake. Also keep your Secret Key secret always

Comment: and also urls.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a typo in your code. You need to change `template_name="polls/details.html"` to `template_name="polls/detail.html"` in your View.

Or, just rename the `polls/detail.html` file to `polls/details.html`.